uniformity in definition of interval for gronwall's lemma
I am following Taylor's book on PDEs and focusing on the hyperbolic part (chapter 16 in my edition). I won't write the full equation and calculations here to keep it clearer for understanding.
I am struggling to understand an application of Gronwall's lemma to prove the existence of solutions to an approximate system of PDEs.
So, we study an approximate PDE, which is $\partial_t u_\epsilon + F_\epsilon(u_\epsilon) = 0$ with the initial condition $u_\epsilon(0) = u_0$ ($F_\epsilon$ is non linear).
By the Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem, we have a solution defined on an interval $I_\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, and (to make it converge to the original problem) we want to show that the solution exists on an interval independent of $\epsilon$.
Denoting $y(t) = \|u_\epsilon(t)\|_{H^k}^2$, the book shows that for $t \in I\epsilon$, $\frac{dy}{dt} \leq E(y)$, where $E$ has the regularity we want.
Here, it says the following, which I do not understand: "Gronwall's inequality yields a function $K(t)$, finite on some interval $[0, B[$, giving an upper bound for all $y(t)$ satisfying the previous inequality."
What I do not understand is the fact that $K$ seems to be defined on an interval that is independent of $\epsilon$, and that we are sure that $B > 0$. Can someone explain this to me, please?

(I wanted to add a 'Hi everyone' at the beginning because I forgot it, but it seems like it's not working haha)
